# Can Tor browser protect me from being found out?

Tags: web-browser, tor

I am using my computer, but am connected to my work's WiFi. Can my company see what websites I visit when am using Tor browser?

Comment: Your work can see that you connect to Tor, which may be worse for you than if they see you browsing Amazon or whatever you're trying to hide.

Comment: General rule of thumb: when at work, stick to work stuff. Don't do non-work stuff on work computers or work networks. This will make your life mich easier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my workplace view my Tor traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65183/can-my-workplace-view-my-tor-traffic)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are using a work computer, they can monitor your activity in any number of *other* ways besides network monitoring. Key loggers, log file monitoring, browser history, software/process monitoring and more are all fair game - in most places you essentially have *no* right to privacy (nada, zero, none!) when using the company's resources. If you raise suspicions by accessing questionable network resources or running unapproved software, expect to get a call from HR about your employment status... As @ConorMancone suggested: just don't do it and life will be *much* easier.